# USB prevent automatic device disconnect due to missing firmware

Tags: debian, wifi, usb, qemu

I have a TP LINK usb wifi adapter. This is what happens when I plug it in:

```
[  153.838373] usb 2-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using ehci-pci
[  153.951203] usb 2-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=..., idProduct=..., bcdDevice= 0.00
[  153.951209] usb 2-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  153.951213] usb 2-1.1: Product: 802.11n NIC
[  153.951216] usb 2-1.1: Manufacturer: Realtek
[  153.951219] usb 2-1.1: SerialNumber: ...
[  153.951823] Chip Version Info: CHIP_8188E_Normal_Chip_TSMC_D_CUT_1T1R_RomVer(0)
[  153.997632] r8188eu 2-1.1:1.0 wlx503...: renamed from wlan0
[  154.028332] r8188eu 2-1.1:1.0: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin (-2)
[  154.028336] r8188eu 2-1.1:1.0: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin failed with error -2
[  154.028338] r8188eu 2-1.1:1.0: Firmware rtlwifi/rtl8188eufw.bin not available
[  154.028340] MAC Address = ...
[  154.126938] usb 2-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[  154.130178] R8188EU: indicate disassoc
```

I understand this is due to some missing firmware.

I don't want to install this firmware on my machine but rather I want to install it to a VM and have that VM use the dongle. Problem is the device is getting immediately disconnected automatically, even though it is physically plugged in, and I can not forward the USB device with Qemu.

Is it possible to prevent the device from being immediately disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd just blacklist the `r8188eu` module – that way, it can't grab the USB device, fail to load the firmware and thus put it in an inoperable state.

Comment: For other noobs like me, [here](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-blacklist-a-module-on-ubuntu-debian-linux)'s how to black list modules.